# C# plus Hyper-V Equals Confusion - Determining Physical NIC

Tags: c#, hyper-v

I am trying to determine which NIC is my actual NIC (in this case a Wifi NIC, but could be Ethernet as well) and tie that back to the active virtual NIC on a host system with Hyper-V installed.

Environment:
Host System: Windows 10, Hyper-V installed with Virtual Switches for the Guest OSes.

Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.6.1

Any ideas? Anyone else seen this?

Here is some code to show that the physical NICs are missing from GetAllNetworkInterfaces(). I would have thought they would be there.

```
var allnetworkinterfaces = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
for (int i = 0; i < allnetworkinterfaces.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} - Description: {1}", allnetworkinterfaces[i].Name, allnetworkinterfaces[i].Description);
}
```

OUTPUT - None of these nor the GUIDs (not shown) match the physical NICs'

```
Name: vEthernet (External - WiFi Adapter) - Description: Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
Name: Local Area Connection* 1 - Description: Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
Name: Local Area Connection* 3 - Description: Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
Name: Bluetooth Network Connection - Description: Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
Name: vEthernet (External - Ethernet Adapter) - Description: Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
Name: Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 - Description: Software Loopback Interface 1
Name: vEthernet (Default Switch) - Description: Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
```

I should mention that I am trying really hard not to use "netsh wlan show interfaces" then matching the MAC addresses, yes admittedly that works. And I've also tried Managed/Native Wifi that only got me so far (opposite problem occurred where I could see physical NIC info minus the MAC address or name, both of which were blank according to managedwifi, I couldn't tie that back to active virtual NIC/Switch without a MAC address)

Clearly somewhere this information is being stored right?

PS
Was trying to use WMI as a last resort only. My team is not a fan of using WMI, I believe they mentioned it was a performance thing as well as a platform porting thing as this code may be ported to macOS at a later time and it is much easier to convert Framework to Core than rip out all the WMI.

Comment: This piece of code is going to be a total rewrite when porting to mac, whether you use WMI or not.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Like I said that isn't their only gripe with WMI. They also claim it is much slower. I'm not opposed to arguing with them about it if it is the only way to go, but I gotta be able to say it is the only way to go. At present I don't even know that WMI is the answer.

Comment: Oh I didn't mean "use WMI", I meant to expect this code to be OS-specific no matter what technology you use for the implementation details.

Comment: Thanks! So far I'm leaning back on netsh, sucks but Native/ManagedWifi don't seem to be able to see the actual physical adapter's Mac address (which can be tied back to the virtual adapter's mac address/cause they match. Where as netsh does/can.